# How can i specify the width of text-decoration underline in CSS

Tags: html, css, reactjs

There is property 'text-decoration: underline' in CSS. I came across an implementation where I have to just put a line half the width of the text and underline needs to be centered, as the attached image

It would be great if somebody tells me how I can specify the width of underline in CSS or how can I implement that style.

[required style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqBiO.png)

Comment: There is an example on jsfiddle with code as well. Try http://jsfiddle.net/9e27b/

Answer (score 2):

You can use `:before` to do this, and it also allows you to adjust the width of the underline and style it accordingly.

```css
p {
font-size: 30px;
display: inline-block;
padding-bottom: 10px;
position: relative;
}

p:before {
content: "";
position: absolute;
width: 50%;
height: 1px;
bottom: 0;
left: 25%;
border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
}
```

```html
<p>HEADLINE</p>
```

Comment: I'm using Navlink from react-router-dom, these styles are not picked by navlink .               <NavLink className="navItem" exact to="/"
                activeStyle={{
                  textDecoration:'underline'
                  //borderBottom: '2px solid currentColor'
                }}
                style={{ textDecoration: 'none' ,paddingLeft: 13,paddingRight: 13}}>
                LESSON PLANNER
              </NavLink>

Comment: I'm not very familiar with React. Can you not apply CSS to `navlink`?

Comment: yeah, I can apply those styles to NavLink and  :before syntax also worked. But the thing I have to deal related to ReactJS is the active style prop, so that only active link gets underlined styles. Thank you for your answer